# Value count over group by does not show count for null/NA values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this-

```
>>> df
     A     B
0  1.0  good
1  2.0  good
2  1.0  good
3  2.0  good
4  1.0   bad
5  1.0   bad
6  2.0   bad
7  2.0   bad
8  NaN  good
```

I want to get count of column B values based on distinct values in column A. So I use groupby as follows, and get the result-

```
>>> df.groupby('A')['B'].value_counts()
A    B   
1.0  bad     2
     good    2
2.0  bad     2
     good    2
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

But it is not showing the count for the `nan` value in column A. What I really want is to show the count for NaN as well-

```
A    B   
1.0  bad     2
     good    2
2.0  bad     2
     good    2
NaN  good    1
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

I even tried to use `dropna = False`, but it is also not showing me expected result.
Can anyone tell me how to get NaN in the result as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A working hack is to cast `A` to string.

```
df.assign(A=df.A.astype(str)).groupby('A')['B'].value_counts()
```

Or, more concisely,

```
df.groupby(df.A.astype(str))['B'].value_counts()
```

```
A    B   
1.0  bad     2
     good    2
2.0  bad     2
     good    2
nan  good    1
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

`groupby` *by default* drops NaNs (missing data) on the grouper, so it is not even considered during the `value_counts` step.

Along the same lines, you can also consider the use of `crosstab`.

```
pd.crosstab(df.A.astype(str), df.B, dropna=False).stack()

A    B   
1.0  bad     2
     good    2
2.0  bad     2
     good    2
nan  bad     0
     good    1
dtype: int64
```

Which also gives you 0 counts.

Comment: Why assign when you can pass that as a grouper i.e `df.groupby(df.A.astype(str))['B'].value_counts()`

Comment: @Dark in general, grouping on a custom grouper is upto 3 times slower than grouping on an existing column. I thought about this and decided to go with the more performant option but I guess it doesn't hurt to specify them both and let OP choose.